# Is there a way to initialize a class with constructed class without using std::move?

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
    int x; 
};

class B {
public:
    B(A &&a) : m_a(std::move(a)) {}
    A m_a;
};

int main()
{
    B var(std::move(A()));
    // B var(A()); // does not compile why?

    std::cout << var.m_a.x << "\n";

}
```

In the above snippet the commented out line doesn't compile. The error message appears that it's treating var like a function declaration. Even if A has a parameter for constructor it's still treated like a function declaration. Is there a way to write it so it won't be treated like function declaration? Using typename doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is known as [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), which exactly describes your situation, where the parser doesn't know if **you** want a function declaration, or the instantiation of an object. It's ambiguous in the sense that, to a human, some given piece of code does *X*, but to the compiler it's clearly doing *Y*.

One way of getting around it is to use the [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) syntax:

```
B var{A()}; // note the use of brackets
```

This is no longer ambiguous, and it will call the constructor as you wanted. You also may use it in `A`, or in both:

```
B var(A{});
B var{A{}};
```

Now, why is it ambiguous? Take for instance the declaration of a function parameter that is a *pointer to function*:

```
int foo(int (*bar)());
```

Here, the parameter is of type *pointer to function that takes no arguments and has return type of int*. Another way to declare pointers to function is by omitting the parentheses in the declarator:

```
int foo(int bar());
```

Which still declares a pointer to function identical to the previous one. As we're in the context of declaring parameters ([parameter-declaration-clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#nt:parameter-declaration-clause)), the grammar being parsed is a [type-id](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#nt:type-id), which is partly built on top of [abstract-declarator](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#nt:abstract-declarator). Therefore, this allows us to remove the identifier:

```
int foo(int());
```

And we still end up with the same type.

With that all said, let's examine your code and compare it to the examples above:

```
B var(A());
```

We have something that looks like a variable declaration of type `B` being initialized with `A()`. So far, so good. But wait, you said this doesn't compile!

> The error message appears that it's treating var like a function declaration.

`var` is in fact a function declaration, even though to you it didn't look like that in the first place. This behavior is due to [[dcl.ambig.res]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.ambig.res-1.sentence-3):

> […] the resolution is to consider any construct that could possibly be a declaration a declaration.

And that sentence applies here. Looking back at the previous examples:

```
int foo(int());
```

That is just as ambiguous as your code: `foo` could possibly be a declaration, so the resolution is to interpret this as one. Your `B var(A())` could possibly be a declaration just as well, so it holds the same resolution.

The standard has a few examples of these cases on [[dcl.ambig.res]/1, example #1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.ambig.res-1.example-1), and also gives some tips on how to disambiguate them on [[dcl.ambig.res]/1, note #1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.ambig.res-1.note-1):

> [ Note: A declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by adding parentheses around the argument.
>   The ambiguity can be avoided by use of copy-initialization or list-initialization syntax, or by use of a non-function-style cast.
>   — end note
>    ]
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   S(int);
> };
>
> void foo(double a) {
>  S w(int(a));                  // function declaration
>  S x(int());                   // function declaration
>  S y((int(a)));                // object declaration
>  S y((int)a);                  // object declaration
>  S z = int(a);                 // object declaration
> }
> ```
>
> — end example
>    ]

Answer (score 2):

Instead construct your `A` like so

```
B var(A{});
```

and it will not be confused for a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
B var = A();
```

Provided that the `B(A&&)` constructor is not `explicit` (in your case, it isn't, so, it is a working approach).

The

```
B var(A{});
```

it's also a working approach to face your problem.

The compiler thinks your original line is a function declaration, because in C++, you can declare anything locally, even functions or structs:

```
int f()
{
   void f(); // You declare that function exists.
   class C; // You declare a class called `C` exists.
}
```

In your case:

```
B var(A());
```

The compiler sees it exists a function called `var`, returning a `B`, and receiving a function which receives no parameters and returns an `A`.

You must disambiguate this with any of the two approaches presented above.